# Come e quando si usa l'espressione "non esser farina da far ostie"?

Tags: word-usage, idioms

Ho a casa da molti anni un libro molto curioso intitolato *Diccionari d'espressions corses comentades*, di Jean-Guy Talamoni. Tratta di modi di dire della lingua corsa, ma è scritto in catalano. Infatti è una traduzione di Mar Bel i Esbrí di un libro scritto in francese, ma è stata un'idea dell'Associazione Corsica-Catalunya. A volte relaziona le espressioni corse con modi di dire simili in altre lingue romanze.

Una delle frasi fatte che ci si trova è

> Quessu ùn hè farina per fà ostia!

che viene tradotta in catalano come "Això no és farina per fer hòsties!". Questa espressione è introdotta in una sezione in cui si presentano parecchi modi di dire per esprimere disprezzo e sfiducia in una persona. Se ne  elencano e spiegano alcuni e poi si afferma "in casi meno gravi si può dire", dopodiché ne appaiono altri, tra cui l'espressione sopra citata.

Come esempio di uso, fa questa citazione della commedia *A Grammatica* di Pierre Toussaint Ricci:

> Lisa: *Pare chi su sgiò Pepé un sia tanta ferina da fa ostia?* 
>   Carl'Antone: *Un birbone, ti dicu!*

C'è una traduzione in catalano di questo piccolo dialogo che, in italiano, più o meno sarebbe:

> Lisa: *Pare che il signor Pepé non sia farina da far ostie?* 
>   Carl'Antone: *Un birbone, ti dico!*

Il libro spiega che questa stessa espressione esiste anche in francese e in italiano. In effetto, sul [dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/F/farina.shtml) si trova

> **non esser farina da far ostie** 
>   Essere una persona da cui è bene badarsi. Il detto è quasi sempre scherzoso, e non è del tutto negativo.

Non riesco a capire, però, come e in quali situazioni si possa usare (se veramente si usa in italiano: se scrivo "farina da far ostie" su Google sembrano apparire espressioni dialettali e libri antichi). Me lo potreste spiegare, facendo qualche esempio?

Comment: L'espressione non mi è del tutto nuova, ma non è certo di uso comune. Aggiungo solo che il _Dizionario dei modi di dire della lingua italiana_ di Carlo Capucci lo considera più o meno un sinonimo di “Non essere uno stinco di santo”.

Comment: @DaG: Forse è diventata di uso piuttosto regionale o arcaico?  Appare, per esempio, in questo [libro di Orlando Pescetti](https://books.google.es/books?id=xXY-AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA75&dq=%22farina+da+far+ostie%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwid8af5y-PoAhUJrxoKHfC2B_AQ6AEwBXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22farina%20da%20far%20ostie%22&f=false).

Comment: Per fare le ostie da consacrare, la farina dev'essere purissima. Uno che “non è farina da far ostie” è forse un bricconcello, ma non necessariamente un poco di buono.

Comment: Vedo che appare anche sul [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI05/00000694.jpg).

Answer (score -1):

I usually use that to say that someone isn't as "good" as they say they are/seem.
Because to make the "ostia" you need the purest flour.

You can use it even jokingly.
Its etymology is Venetian so it'is more like a local saying.

Edit: I'm Italian.

Comment: Se sei italiano perché scrivi in inglese? Sarebbe interessante sapere qualcosa di più sull'origine veneziana della locuzione. Hai una fonte?

Comment: Grazie. C'è l'usanza di rispondere in italiano a domande in italiano e in inglese a domande in inglese. Puoi inserire la fonte nella risposta, se è pertinente? Grazie!

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta, ma non riesco a visualizzare la pagina di questo vocabolario in cui si parla del modo di dire "non esser farina da far ostie". Potresti aggiungere la informazione rilevante alla risposta (e citare la fonte, ovviamente)?

Comment: E poi, tu usi questa espressione perché sei veneto? O è semplicemente che si usa in altre regioni d'Italia?

Comment: Riguardo a quello che ha detto @DaG, puoi dare un'occhiata a questa [domanda sul sito Meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/) e alle sue risposte. Personalmente, preferisco una risposta in italiano (oppure bilingue) perché è quello che mi aiuta di più a imparare la lingua.